# How to get all external or internal css used in page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want functionality to get all the external or internal css used in page using jQuery,java script.

or

Any functionality that convert external or internal css used in page to in-line css.

Answer (score 0):

The tool inline-css will inline css:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css

Comment: In this internal CSS is converted into in-line CSS !! What about external CSS used in HTML page ??